# Characters of a Group: two definitions

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, characters

If $G$ is an *abelian* group, the characters associated to the rapresentations of $G$ over $\textrm{GL}_1(\mathbb C)=\mathbb C^\ast$ are simply the group homomorphisms:

$$\chi:G\longrightarrow\mathbb C^\ast$$

On the contrary if $G$ is a topological group (assume locally compact) then a character is a continous homomorphism:
$$\chi':G\longrightarrow\mathbb R/\mathbb Z\cong S^1$$

Why do we have two apparently different definitions? I know that the range of $\chi$ (first definition) is $S^1$ only when $G$ is finite.

Comment: I've seen the first definition referred to as *quasi-characters*, eg. in Tate's thesis.

Comment: Wikipedia call them simply characters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_group

I'm a bit confused

Comment: Oh yeah abelian groups. I'm sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreeing with Adam in the comments: if the bigger codomain $\Bbb C^*$ is used we have what number theory would term a *quasicharacter*, at least from what I've read. True, from the viewpoint of representation theory, it's just a one-dimensional character. However for convenience and elegance we sometimes impose *unitarity* on our representations, and stipulating that the codomain be $S^1$ is essentially saying we want it to be a unitary one-dimensional representation.

KCd in [another thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124379/why-unitary-characters-for-the-dual-group-in-pontryagin-duality-if-g-is-not-co) states why $U(1)$ is so useful: it is the "universal dualizer," which is where we get Pontryagin duality. Precisely: $G\cong\hom(\hom(G,A),A)$ for all loc. comp. $G$ iff $A=U(1)$.