# Intuition behind Pontryagin duality

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups

We have that for a locally compact abelian group,

$$A \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}(A, \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$$

is a biduality map when endowing $\operatorname{Hom}$ with the compact-open topology.

My question is why $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$? This sounds like a rather counter-intuitive result. I can see one why one would give $\operatorname{Hom}$ the compact-open topology (there are many categorical and topological reasons to do this) but it looks rather ad-hoc that we use the circle group.

How did this come up? Are there other bidualities using different groups?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294019/why-the-circle-for-pontryagin-duality

Comment: It is in fact explained in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124379/why-unitary-characters-for-the-dual-group-in-pontryagin-duality-if-g-is-not-co). Read the first comment by Kcd. His $U(1)$ is your $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$. And he cited Hewitt and Ross  vol. 1 p. 424 as well as Pontryagin's book *Topological Groups* Example 72. I didn't check any of the citations.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The fundamental notion behind the theory of groups is the concept of *symmetries* and the best place to visualize symmetries is Euclidean space and, by extension, Hilbert's space.

By a symmetry on a Hilbert space $H$ one means any map
$$
  U:H\to H
  $$
that preserves distance, and sends the origin to itself.  In fact any such map is necessarily a unitary operator.

The group $\mathscr U(H)$, formed by all unitary operators on Hilbert's space  is, according to this, the archetype of symmetry!

Given any group $G$, it therefore makes a lot of sense  to try to  model $G$ via  $\mathscr U(H)$,  and this is usually done by considering
group homomorphisms
$$
  u:G\to \mathscr U(H),
  $$
often called  *group representations*.

If $u_1$ and $u_2$ are representations of $G$,  one may define a direct sum representation
$$
  u=u_1\oplus u_2
  \tag 1
  $$
on $H\oplus H$,  but
everything there is to know about $u$ is already present in either $u_1$ or $u_2$.

On the other hand, should we be
interested in studying a given representation $u$, we might ask whether or not it has an expression such as (1), in
which case   it
would be better to study $u_1$ and $u_2$ separately.

This means that one should concentrate in the study of *irreducible* group representations, namely those  which cannot
be split as in (1).

For abelian groups, Schur's Lemma says that all irreducible unitary representations are necessarily one-dimensional,
meaning that the underlying  Hilbert space is $\mathbb C$, and since
$$
  \mathscr U(\mathbb C) = \mathbb T,
  $$
we are inexorably led to  studying homomorphisms from $G$ to $\mathbb T$!

Comment: This is a very vivid, nice explanation.